# File Object from Camel-exchange body is null in Camel FTP

Tags: file-io, null, unmarshalling, jaxb2, camel-ftp

The route definition is simple based on FTP2 component.

```
        Endpoint[sftp://server.com:22//path/to/file/?consumer.delay=900000&password=xxxxxx&username=user]
```

I am trying to read a file from a FTP folder.

```
   JAXBContext jaxBContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(ObjectFactory.class);
   Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jaxBContext.createUnmarshaller();
   File authBatchFile = exchange.getIn().getBody(File.class);
   AuthorizationFeed batchAuthFeed = (AuthorizationFeed) JAXBIntrospector
            .getValue(unmarshaller.unmarshal(authBatchFile));
```

The exchange has everything it should have

```
    Body                [Body is file based: RemoteFile[fileName.txt]]
```

Header also shows the size of the file ***CamelFileLength=81612***. However, I am getting the below exception just after the exchange trace.

```
  java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The value for the "java.io.File" parameter cannot be null.
at com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.jaxb.unmarshal.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.reportNullParameter(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:180)
at com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.jaxb.unmarshal.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:72)
at com.wellpoint.clihub.hie.um.camel.processor.BatchCFFProcessor.process(BatchCFFProcessor.java:47)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the solution to it by adding to the route definition

```
&localWorkDirectory=/tmp.
```

That way it doesn't consider it to be a remote file and considers it to be a ***java.io.File***. I think Camel should incorporate that as a default feature when dealing with remote files. Per their documentation,

> The route above is ultra efficient as it avoids reading the entire file content into memory. It will download the remote file directly to a local file stream. The java.io.File handle is then used as the Exchange body.